# Use RegEx to convert hexadecimal values in text into ascii characters

Tags: regex, vba, ms-access, notepad++

I've been put in charge of a project maintaining and updating a database built in Microsoft Access. Right now I'm using the regular expression replacement feature of Notepad++ to reformat queries written as strings in its VBA code into SQL queries that can be run directly.

The current piece I'm working on is converting its common use of

```
    Chr(&Hxx)
```

where 'xx' is a two-digit hexadecimal value, to express ASCII characters based on value.

I've tried using the search/replace pairing

```
    [Cc]hr\(\&[Hh]([\da-fA-F]{2,2})\)

    \x($1)
```

which, it seems, should extract the hex value as $1 and then render the ASCII value as a character, but instead produces an 'x' followed by the two-digit hex value. It may simply be that this only works when used with a literal, rather than a replacement value being pulled out of the text.

Any ideas on how to convert a hex value in the text into its corresponding ASCII character?

Comment: You're asking a regex to *interpret* the data it's capturing. That's not what regex is for.

Comment: Tagged with VBA and VB.Net. Is it one or the other, or both?

Comment: @djv, this portion of the language is identical so both fit. The question is more about using regular expression search/replace on code than the language itself, however.

Comment: @bükWyrm then I have added vb6 as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular expression *matches* strings against a pattern, and you can use these matches to perform replacements.

Your pattern *does* extract the hex value as `$1` ...and then you replace it with `$1` ...which is the exact hex value you've extracted.

The problem is that you need a piece of logic to *interpret* the captured hex values, to *convert* them to their character representation - a regex alone doesn't know how to do that. Not for *any match* anyway.

What you *can* do is perform multiple replacements, each time matching a different hex value, and replacing it with the equivalent character, e.g.:

```
[Cc]hr\(\&[Hh]22\)
```

And replace that with a `"` (&H22 would be ASCII 34, the double-quote character).

If you can't do that and *require* a more automated way, then you need to write a script to do it, in whichever language you like.

Comment: That makes sense. Regex passively performs substitutions, whereas my attempt assumed an active operation wherein it recursively performed a substitution upon the replacement value.